# Android - How to do a touchable scroll paper animation?

Tags: android

I would like to show to the users a 3D closed scroll paper what they can roll out with their fingers. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: is there an example you can link to illustrate this? Have you looked into anything yet?

Comment: Something like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWy_ZD4pJMk

Answer (score 1):

To achieve an affect like the one you want, the 1st thing you'll need is a **Graphic Designer**

You'll need two graphic assets in particular:

1. The full image of the rolled out parchment without the bottom rolling part
2. The bottom part of the parchment - for this you're going to need multiple frames (to animate the rolling). So you'll need 1 image per frame of the rolling animation.

Once you have these assets, you'll need to lay them out properly.

I would recommend something like this layout (pseudo-layout):

```
<LinearLayout - vertical, this will be your main container>
    <RelativeLayout - will start at a small height, and will grow with animation. Should crop children>
       <ImageView - with the top & center part of the parchment
                  - give this view an explicit height which is equal to the fully 
                    extended size of the parent layout/>
       <... any additional layouts or views />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView - contains a single frame of the rolling bottom part
               - replace the image with the next frame every few milliseconds/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Conceptually, this should be sufficient to gain the effect that you want.

Apologies for the abstractness of the answer, but since you didn't post any of the code that you've tried (I'm assuming you haven't tried anything yet), there wasn't a lot for me to work with.

Hopefully, this gives you enough ideas to get you started.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out. Yes, I haven't done anything yet, because I didn't know how to start. I appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: Are there any tutorial which would be helpful?

Comment: It would be hard to find a tutorial which covers this specific need. It's really all about knowing the tools you have, and figuring out how to use them to get you where you need.

Comment: If it would be enough to do something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8YBGtjY5eo
How could I do it?

Comment: well that looks a bit simpler, since you wouldn't need to animate a rolling parchment. whether or not you should? it's really not me you should be asking - it depends if that's enough for your requirements.